# What to do if the intent isn't recognized in Rasa?

Tags: python, nlp

I followed the weather rasa chatbot one provided by [Justina Petraityte](https://vimeo.com/254777331), you can find the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/JustinaPetr/Weatherbot_Tutorial). Yet my chatbot never recognizes the intent I try to provide him, which has to be the location,  and I don't know how to handle this case as far as it create an error when calling for the weather API, which is therefore empty.

For instance I tried to ask for a the weather in Italy but, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jubgb.png). It don't recognizes Italy as an intent even if it was in `data.json`.

For instance :

[Image where we can see an example where he doesn't recognizes the intent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01MdL.png)

Therefore, what to do when the intent isn't recognized ? Should we still save it to the stories.md ?

**Content of domain file** :

```
action_factory: null
action_names:
- utter_greet
- utter_goodbye
- utter_ask_location
- action_weather
actions:
- utter_greet
- utter_goodbye
- utter_ask_location
- actions.ActionWeather
config:
  store_entities_as_slots: true
entities:
- location
intents:
- greet
- goodbye
- inform
slots:
  location:
    initial_value: null
    type: rasa_core.slots.TextSlot
templates:
  utter_ask_location:
  - text: In what location?
  utter_goodbye:
  - text: Talk to you later.
  - text: Bye bye :(
  utter_greet:
  - text: Hello! How can I help?
topics: []
```

**Rasa Core version**:

```
(MoodbotEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/moodbot4$ pip list :
...
rasa-core (0.9.0a3)
rasa-nlu (0.12.3)
```

**Python version**:

```
(MoodbotEnv) mike@mike-thinks:~/Programing/Rasa_tutorial/moodbot4$ python -V 
Python 3.5.2
```

**Operating system** :

```
Linux 16.04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have at least 2-10 examples for each intent
The more training examples you have the better.

I would recommend to use the Tensorflow, Spacy, CRF backend combination and 5-10 examples for each intent, **works amazingly well for me!** 
Use this as your config.yml

```
pipeline:
- name: "intent_featurizer_count_vectors"
- name: "intent_classifier_tensorflow_embedding"
  batch_size: 64
  epochs: 1500
- name: "nlp_spacy"
- name: "tokenizer_spacy"
- name: "ner_crf"
```

Here is a guide how to build the previous version all you have to do, after finish the tut, is changing the config file to switch to TF backend.

Follow this one - cook book to build an **on premise** chatbot with python using RASA NLU:
[Step by step (cookbook) to build your chatbot](https://chatbotslife.com/build-simple-chatbot-with-rasa-part-1-f4c6d5bb1aea)

Comment: In my case, sometimes it took a minimum three examples for the intent to be recognized (even wrongly).